# segue creating new instance of view controller swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, viewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have an app with four view controllers. The navigation between 1, 2 and 3 is fine but from view controller 1 you have the option of going to 2 or to 4 (which is my settings) I have a segue from 1 to 4. I then use an unwind segue to get back. but when I use the segue back to 4 it instantiates a new instance of 4.

My Question: Is there any way to access the same instance of a view controller that the user had last time.

Comment: You could keep a reference to that view controller and push it rather than using a segue, by nil you are using a navigation controller you would typically just push a new instance, configuring it as required

Comment: sorry I am kind of a newbee and do not know what you mean. could you please explain in more detail

Answer (score 2):

Just like what @Paul11 said in the comments you should keep a **reference** of the `UIViewController` you're trying to push if you want the same instance to be accessed

Say for example

```
var someViewController = SomeViewController() // << this is at the class level scope

func someSampleFunc() {
    // doing this would create a new instance of the `SomeViewController` every time you push
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SomeViewController(), animated: true)

    // whereas if you use the variable which is at the class level scope the memory instance is kept
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(someViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Another example for instances

```
class Bro {
    var name = "Some Name"

    func sayDude() {          
        // since `name` is a class level you can access him here

        let dude = "DUUUUUUUDE" // this variable's lifetime only exists inside the `sayDude` function, therefore everytime you call `sayDude()` a new instance of `dude` is created

        print(name)
        print(dude)
    }

    func doBackflip() {
         sayDude() //

         print(name + " does backflip") // since `name` is a class level you can access him here
    }
}
```

Comment: @c3pNoah mark me as the correct answer and upvote if it helped thanks